# Is there any way to monitor ram usage of one vm from another using nod js monitoring api

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-monitoring

I need to monitor ram usage of machine A from machine B running node js application on google cloud. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stackdriver for Node.js outlined in link [1] and Monitoring Client Libraries [2] with source code mentioned in link [3]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/stackdriver
[2] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs
[3] https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-monitoring